# Understanding basic DOM structure and load sequence of a web application

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-applications, execution

I'm trying to get started with web application development, and understand how everything works together at a high level, including:

- understanding "front-end" and "back-end"
- basic structure of DOM
- sequence of events for web application

I've found help on [order of execution for web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151833/order-of-execution-in-web-environment) and [HTML order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page), but I'm having trouble understanding how everything works together at a high level. The way I learn best is by drawing it out. Are my drawings correct?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The diagrams look right to me.  Is there a specific question you had about them?  Some minor additions: `<script>` tags don't have to be only in the `<head>` section - they can also be in the `<body>` section.  [Unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) suggests that you don't embed event handlers in your HTML with things like `onclick=xxx`, but rather install the event handlers via initialization javascript with `elem.addEventListener()`.

Comment: javascript being `ondemand` isn't very accurate since lots of script may have nothing to do with user interaction